# Not able to understand the output of my program

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, stl, c++14

Description - I am using c++ stl lists to solve a problem. A part of the problem involves finding the no. of distict charachters in a string.

My Approach - I have created a list. copied the elements of 'str' to it. sorted the list. removed all duplicate element and am trying to copy the unique element s into a new string 'str2'.

Question - when I copy the content of the list to the new string str2, the value of *it when copied to str2 does not seem to match why is this happening?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    list<char> l1;
    string str;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>str;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        l1.push_back(str[i]);
    }
    l1.sort();
    l1.unique();
    string str2;
    int x=0;
    for(list<char>::iterator it=l1.begin();it!=l1.end();++it){
        str2[x]=*it;
        cout<<"x"<<x;
        cout<<*it<<" ";
        cout<<str[x]<<" "<<endl;
        ++x;
    }
    int n2=str2.length();
    for(int i=0;i<n2;++i){
        cout<<str2[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

curro/p -

```
x0a b 
x1b e 
x2e a 
x3f b
```

o/p I want -

```
x0a a 
x1b b 
x2e e 
x3f f
```

Comment: I don't get it. `str` is your input isn't it ? And you never modify it, right ? So why would it be equal to your output ?

Comment: sorry my bad. I will delete this question

Answer (score 1):

You get this because `str2` is empty. Indexing it here `str2[x]=*it` causes undefined behavior.

You can fix this by allocating space to `str2` based on the length of the original string `str`, and filling it with some characters that you don't use in the actual string (I used `'-'` below)

```
string str2(str.size(), '-');
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/3EOtRe)

Comment: thank you. I understood my mistake. I will delete this question now as it would not be useful for others.